# Should I update my Gemfile or my Gemfile.lock for an activesupport update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile, activesupport, gemfile.lock

I got a dependabot alert on one of my personal projects on Github, asking me to `Upgrade activesupport to version 6.0.3.1 or later.` It has suggested that I do something like `gem "activesupport", ">= 6.0.3.1"`. My question is, do I directly update my `Gemfile.lock`? Or do I add this line to my `Gemfile` and let `bundler` update the `Gemfile.lock`?

One reason I am confused is that my `Gemfile` currently has no reference to `activesupport`, so I'm not sure if I should add that line to the `Gemfile` at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Active Support** is one of **Rails** dependencies. You should not modify **Gemfile.lock** manually. Instead, update the rails version in **Gemfile**, for example:

```
gem "rails", "6.0.3.1"
```

if you want the exact version to be installed, or:

```
gem "rails", "~> 6.0.3"
```

to install latest version **>= 6.0.3** and **< 6.1**.

After that, run:

```
$ bundle update rails
```

This should update rails and its dependencies like actiontext, actionview and so on.